# Actions from different XIB?

Tags: xcode, xib, ibaction

I have a XIB (RootViewController) that has actions I want to do from a different XIB (DetailViewController) but I can't seem to do it.

I've imported the .h file and used this code:

```
myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:RootViewController selector: @selector(updateAlbumsAfterLogin) userInfo: nil repeats: NO];
```

I get this error:

```
Expected expression before 'RootViewController'
```

There's probably a simple fix and I am going to feel stupid. Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

Look what I did:

```
RootViewController *controller = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(updateAlbums) toTarget:controller withObject:nil];
```

I do a NSLog on it and it displays. But it's not doing the rest of the action like it was when I had a timer to it every 10 seconds before. Any ideas?

** EDIT: **

It might be unclear to what I want to do. I have a view that slides up if the user doesn't have information on file. After the login and it's a success, I want it to close then refresh and check fro albums in a different XIB. I have trial all sorts of things, but none seem to work! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like your target is a class and not an instance of a class. You need to target an instance of that class.

Comment: Look what I did:

`RootViewController *controller = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
  [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(updateAlbums) toTarget:controller withObject:nil];` I do a NSLog on it and it displays. But it's not doing the rest of the action like it was when I had a timer to it every 10 seconds before. Any ideas?

Comment: you're making the controller right before? this is not normally how you would init something from a XIB. Is it later added to the current view's subviews? I suspect you are messaging the wrong controller instance.  Also do you see an error on the console of any kind?

Comment: I tried doing this in my second class: `IBOutlet SecondViewController *controller;` but interface buiilder won't let me connect it to a different XIB.